# curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused

Tags: curl, localhost

I am trying to post my image to begin resized through api which I got from sam lcoal start-api.

```
docker exec -it test_container curl -H "Accept: image/png" -H "Content-Type: image/png" --data-binary "cat3.png" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello -o test.png
```

error is:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused
```

expect result would be resize the image. But here I found the error.Can anyone please help me throughout this?

Comment: What have you configured such that your container should serve something on port 3000?

Comment: This is not a curl question but about the server application you are running inside the docker. Please edit and tag your question accordingly so people who know something about it can find your question.